# How to Loop Through a const char**?

Tags: c++, pointers, glfw

I have a `const char**` called `glfwNames` which holds the C version of a string array of the required GLFW library extensions. Would it be possible to loop through either the const char* (string), or the individual characters of the string separated by `'\0'`?

```
    const char** glfwNames = glfwGetRequiredInstanceExtensions(&glfwCount)

    for (const char** name = glfwNames; *name; ++name)
    {
         slog("GLFW Extensions to use: %s", *name);
    }
```

This is what I've attempted from one of the answers, and the return value of

```
glfwGetRequiredInstanceExtensions
```

is an array of extension names, required by GLFW http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__vulkan.html#ga1abcbe61033958f22f63ef82008874b1

Comment: Please provide a complete example, not just a vague description of some code. If this is an array of `char*` then just loop over it until you hit some kind of list terminator, typically `nullptr`. Do you know how to use pointers as arrays like `p[0]` and `p[i]` and so on?

Comment: Is the return value of the function zero terminated? Not each individual string, but the array of strings as a whole

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `glfwNames` is `nullptr`-terminated:

```
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    char const *glfwNames[] = { "foo", "bar", "baz", nullptr };
    for (char const **p = glfwNames; *p; ++p)
        std::puts(*p);
}
```

If you *know* the number of strings:

```
std::uint32_t glfwCount;
const char** glfwNames = glfwGetRequiredInstanceExtensions(&glfwCount)

for (std::uint32_t i{}; i < glfwCount; ++i)
{
     slog("GLFW Extensions to use: %s", glfwNames[i]);
}
```

To also loop through the individual `char`s:

```
for (std::uint32_t i{}; i < glfwCount; ++i)
{
     for(char const *p{ glfwNames[i] }; *p; ++p)
         std::putchar(*p);
}
```

Comment: Good stuff! Your second example was exactly what I needed. I wasn't sure if I could get the names directly or if I'd have to parse the characters.

Answer (score 0):

A common pattern that I use to loop through the arguments to `main` is via `std::for_each`:

```
#include <algorithm>
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::for_each( argv + 1, argv + argc, handler );
}
```

where `handler` is any function taking a `const char*`, `const std::string&`, or `std::string_view` (I use the later).

Would a similar approach work for your problem? Notice that this approach requires you to know the length of your array of strings.

As a side note, it is important to know that the return argument of `std::for_each` is the function provided (`handler` in this case). That enables the suggested pattern to make a last call once the input is known to have been exhausted:

```
#include <algorithm>
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::for_each( argv + 1, argv + argc, handler )("Argument To Last Call");
}
```

This can be used to implement state machines that receive the termination trigger at the end.